# Moving HTML closing tag to end of paragraph line after autocompletion in vs code

Tags: html, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

At times you would have a line of paragraph and when adding html opening tag at beginning of line visual studio code would autocomplete and add closing tag for you at the beginning of paragraph line. Can I move the closing tag to end of line with a shortcut without having to delete the closing tag and retyping it at the end of line? Thanks!

Comment: htmltagwrap, a suggested extension, worked well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This extention does what you want but with shortcuts. You have select the text that you want to put in the `<p></p>` tag and then create the tag with alt+w
the GIF explain it in the link

[VS Code Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradgashler.htmltagwrap)

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!